# Count total distinct elements along with distinct elements within groups

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to count the total number of distinct elements in a table as well as the number of distinct elements in a group. I can get the distinct for a group but I'm having trouble getting total distinct after grouping.

For example say we have a table:

```
Employees:

First_Name , Division 

Jon, Marketing

Jon, Advertising

Mary, Sales

James, Engineering
```

If I do :

```
COUNT( UNIQUE(First_Name) )
GROUP BY Division
```

I will get as a result the count of the unique First_Name per group, but how would I get the unique first names for the ENTIRE table. My intution is to use a With clause but I'm not sure how to combine that with the GROUP BY.

My desired result is to have something that looks like:

```
Division-------Distinct Count

Marketing--------1

Advertising------1

Sales------1

Engineering------1

Total Distinct Users-------3
```

Comment: Afaik Oracle supports *Extended Grouping*, try: `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Division), ())`

Comment: I will look into that, thanks